# Install wxWidgets-3.1.4, Install Code::Blocks

Tags: compiling, makefile, code-blocks

After downloading and installing (`./configure, make install`) the latest wxWidgets-3.1.4 version from official page. I checked out latest Code::sBlocks with svn from official repository.
In the folder trunk I did `./bootstrap`, but then I get the following error:

*configure.ac:141: warning: macro 'AM_OPTIONS_WXCONFIG' not found in library
configure.ac:142: warning: macro 'AM_PATH_WXCONFIG' not found in library
configure.ac:26: installing './compile'
configure.ac:22: installing './missing'
src/base/tinyxml/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
configure.ac:141: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_OPTIONS_WXCONFIG
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:142: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_WXCONFIG*

Do I must export the PATH from wxconfig?
Any help is appreciated. I can't install wxWidgets-3.1.4 and build Code::Blocks.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Norbert 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start by using related packages from the official repositories:

- Codeblocks 16.01 [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/codeblocks):

  ```
  sudo apt-add-reposotitory universe
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-dev
  ```
- WxWidgets 3.0.4 [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/wxwidgets3.0)

  ```
  sudo apt-add-reposotitory universe
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev
  ```

and then compile some wxWidgets test program using CodeBlocks.

---

If you are sure that you need to compile both programs by yourself - then  start with installing build-dependencies by:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep codeblocks wxwidgets3.0
```

and then retry your build procedure.